# multiple inheritance issue Swift

Tags: ios, swift, inheritance, uiviewcontroller

I have a problem with multiple inheritance in Swift , this is my situation:

In my App I have various `UITableViewController` and `UIViewController` but both must have various fields for example an array and two strings.
For this reason I thought to create a superclass `'SuperClassTest'` and the all `UITableViewController` and `UIViewController` inherit from it , like this:

```
class SuperClassTest {

    var stringOne:String?
    var stringTwo:String?
}
```

My problem is that when I create,for example, a `UIViewController` that has to have those fields , it can't inheritance from `SuperClassTest` because it already inherits from `UIViewController` class.

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: Your question title is very misleading. Swift doesn't support multiple inheritance

Comment: ... and `UITableViewController` inherits from `UIViewController` anyway.

Comment: @SahebRoy in what way is it misleading?

Comment: "multiple inheritance issue Swift"  when swift doesn't support multiple inheritance. Isn't that misleading?

Comment: No, it is an obvious mistake by OP which we can easily resolve. The problem is that he wants "multiple inheritance" but could not figure out how to achieve that on his own.

Comment: composition instead of inheritance.

Comment: @Sulthan can you explain better your way?

Comment: @Sulthan is referring to the same thing as the answers: composition of protocols rather tan inheritance of classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't implement multiple inheritance in Objective C and Swift. But you can achieve this by Multi-level inheritance.

```
class SuperClassViewController : UIViewController
{
    var stringOne:String?
    var stringTwo:String?
}

class YourViewController : SuperClassViewController
{
}
```

Comment: my problem is that I have a lot of class that has to have those fields , for example uiviewcontroller , uitableviewcontroller and other. In this way I must replace those fields for every class

Answer (score 3):

Swift and Objective-C are single inheritance only, you can't have more than one superclass for a class.

When you see Swift code with what looks like multiple superclasses in their declaration, you'll see that at most, one of the names in the declaration is a superclass, the others are names of protocols.

Comment: I know it , my question is how do I resolve my problem not being able to use multiple inheritance

Answer (score 1):

You add your "superclass" as a protocol instead:

```
Protocol SuperProtocolTest {

    var stringOne:String?
    var stringTwo:String?
}
```

You can then use your protocol as necessary blueprints for the classes you want to conform to it:

```
Class MyController : UITableViewController, SuperProtocolTest { 
    ...
}
```

Swift is said to be a language of *protocol oriented programming* (POP), rather then OOP. You can't have multiple inheritance, but you can let a class of yours conform to as many protocols as you want, e.g.

```
Class MyController : UITableViewController, SuperProtocolTest, UITextFieldDelegate, ... { 
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As already said: you can only inherit one class, but can conform to as many protocols as you wish.

There the obvious solutions is to create a protocol containing all the required vars and conform to that protocol:

```
protocol ImportantPropertiesToHave {
    var stringOne : String? { get }
    var stringTwo : String? { get set }
}

class MyClass : UIViewController, ImportantPropertiesToHave {
    let stringOne : String? = "hi"
    var stringTwo : String? = nil
}
```

You have to specify in the protocol wether it is a readonly variable or a read-write one. Then the variables you define in your implementation have to at least match that criteria.

If the protocols something to be at least `get` your implementation can chose to make it a public variable. If the protocol however wants it to be `get set` your implementation must not use a `let` but has to use `var`.